# Certificate pinning with public hash in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, certificate, pinning

**My Problem statement:**

My host got 3 certificates. 
I need to check atleast one certificate is valid from my app. 
I have copied all public key hashes for these certificates to my app in a dictionary.

I have been using default Apple Security framework APIs to get all the certificates from server.

Everything works fine if I do it in iOS 9+, if I use,

`SecCertificateCopyPublicKey(serverCertificate)`

I am getting all the three certificates which I can verify. 
But the issue is with iOS 8. It will give only serverTrust public key.

Is there any API from Apple which I can use for version iOS 8 to get multiple certificates public key hashes hosted in a single host?

Comment: People actually still support pre iOS 9? I would consider supporting "only" iOS 9+. My guess is that is 99% of the devices.

Comment: We still have some thousand people in our application and hence cannot lose them.

Comment: Do you have any stats on how many of them are actually on iOS 8?

Comment: They are returning all the certificates. But in iOS 8, you can only get the public key for serverTrust. So ideally I will get to compare with only one certificate which is not my requirement.

Comment: @thoughtbreaker isn't 'SecCertificateCopyPublicKey' only available in iOS 10.3 or newer?